# How to get search feed from Pinterest API

Tags: pinterest

I am looking to search feed of `Pinterest` API for Mobile Application.
May i know how to get search feed from `Pinterest` API.

Comment: I don't know. May you? What have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to get search feed in Json/Xml which will be available of Pinterest.

Comment: You have to be more specific. What interface are you using? What have you tried!!

Comment: I want to show Pinterest Search data on my web & wap Page.
So I am looking for API.

Comment: Have you used JQuery?

Comment: No, I just want to read Feed if they will provide by API or response  Json/XMl what ever Pinterest provide. Just want to get search feed.

Comment: @RaviGupta Any solution you found?

Answer (score 1):

This is deprecated as of 2019 and I think [this](https://github.com/cypherpunk99/guipinterest/blob/master/app/pinterest-api/api/constants.js) can be a valid place to find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use unofficial api, with py3-pinterest you can do it like this in python

```
results = []
search_batch = pinterest.search(scope='boards', query='food')
while len(search_batch) > 0:
    results += search_batch
# do whatever with results
```

[full code example](https://github.com/bstoilov/py3-pinterest/blob/master/examples.py#L128)

Comment: does it work with azure functions or aws lambda?

Comment: sure why not. I haven't used azure, but for AWS lambda you have to add a layer with the dependency in it.

Comment: I checked the requirements and it says it requires chrome to log in. What could I do about that?

Comment: I don't know, you could try to run the healess chrome inside the lambda

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation here https://developers.pinterest.com/api_docs/ about their api, however it is only for queries about domains that are verified and belong to your Pinterest account.